# How to copy-paste in good quality from Adobe Illustrator to MS One Note?

Tags: copy-paste, adobe-illustrator, microsoft-onenote

When I copy some drawing in Illustrator, it stores it in clipboard in 3 formats: bitmap, device independent bitmap and enhanced meta-file.

If drawing contains text, then meta-file version has no anti-aliasing.

Below are examples in MS Word

[image]

OneNote has no "Paste Special" so it always paste in EMF. Is it possible either to tell OneNote to paste not in EMF, or tell Illustrator to use anti-aliasing while storing picture with letters?

Comment: Paste into Word or paint first, then copy the result?

Comment: What version of OneNote is this?

Comment: One note 2010...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly what you are seeing is due to OneNote resizing the image you pasted.

After the image has been paste into OneNote, select the image and right-click on it.

In the pop-up there is the option to "Restore to Original Size".

Select this option to restore the image to its original size, hopefully removing the jaggies you are witnessing.

Comment: No, this didn't help. Restored image became bigger but still not anti-aliased.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround!

1. Download/Install One Note iPhone App
2. Open a note
3. Click the Share button and choose "Email Page". ***Your iPhone email client will convert it to a One Page PDF***
4. Email it to yourself and open the PDF.
5. Open the PDF in Illustrator